# Hide folded lines in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to hide the folded lines in Sublime Text 3 when doing a filtering with the [Filter Lines](https://github.com/davidpeckham/FilterLines) plugin? It would give a great benefit being able to edit multiple lines without using the mouse - otherwise I need to select individual lines with the mouse to avoid selecting the folded lines.

If it is not possible to avoid it in combination with `Filter Lines` can it then be globally disabled?

I do not want to show the yellow/folded lines when filtering:

[image]